# How to remove element from an array using reduce?

Tags: javascript, typescript, ecmascript-6, filter

Trying to filter out object based on some logic below code is returning empty array any help will be appreciated trying to achieve following logic

1- If first Obj (firstFillIndicator=Y, acceptDigitalFirstFill=Y) and Second Object(firstFillIndicator = Y, acceptDigitalFirstFill=N). this object should be removed its falsy.

2- if first obj(firstFillIndicator=Y, acceptDigitalFirstFill=Y) and seond object (firstFillIndicator= N, acceptDigitalFirstFill=Y).  this object should be removed its falsy.

3- if both objects have firstFillIndicator and acceptDigitalFirstFill have some values that would be truthy.

main.ts

```
function validateSingleOrder(data){
  let isValid = false;
  const filteredDrugs = data.filter((item) => {
      isValid = isValidOrder(item);
      if(isValid){
        return true;
      } else {
        return false;
      }
  })

 return filteredDrugs;
}

function isValidOrder(item){
   item.rxInfos.reduce((a, c) => {
    return (a.acceptDigitalFirstFill === "Y" && c.firstFillIndicator === "Y") || (a.firstFillIndicator === "N" && c.acceptDigitalFirstFill === "N")
  });
}

console.log(validateSingleOrder(rxDetails));
```

data

```
 const rxDetails = [
      {
            indexID: 1,
            rxInfos: [{
                    firstFillIndicator: "Y",
                    acceptDigitalFirstFill: "Y",
                    rxNumber: "1512"
                },
                {
                    firstFillIndicator: "Y",
                    acceptDigitalFirstFill: "N",
                    rxNumber: "16021"

                }
            ]
      },
      {
          indexID: 2,
          rxInfos: [{
                  firstFillIndicator: "Y",
                  acceptDigitalFirstFill: "Y",
                  rxNumber: "1512"
              },
              {
                  firstFillIndicator: "N",
                  acceptDigitalFirstFill: "Y",
                  rxNumber: "16021"

              }
          ]
      },
      {
          indexID: 3,
          rxInfos: [{
                  firstFillIndicator: "Y",
                  acceptDigitalFirstFill: "Y",
                  rxNumber: "1512"
              },
              {
                  firstFillIndicator: "N",
                  acceptDigitalFirstFill: "N",
                  rxNumber: "16021"

              }
          ]
      }
    ]
```

expected result

```
[{
        indexID: 3
        rxInfoss: [{
                firstFillIndicator: "Y",
                acceptDigitalFirstFill: "Y",
                rxNumber: "1512"
            },
            {
                firstFillIndicator: "N",
                acceptDigitalFirstFill: "N",
                rxNumber: "16021"

            }
        ]
    },

];
```

Comment: Do not use reduce, you won't need it for this use case.

Comment: `isValidOrder()` doesn't ever return a value, so would always evaluate to `false`.

Comment: Why use `reduce` here? You *can* but you should also be returning a value for the accumulator each time - you're not doing that. You're just comparing two objects at a time and...that's it.

Comment: Try using filter instead of reduce

Comment: I'm actually surprised this doesn't throw errors. You should get them for any length over `2`, as you try to dereference properties off `a` which will be a boolean value.

Comment: @Timo what would be better approach can you give me an example i have to iterate over child rxInfos elements to see if they have these values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that the `isValidOrder` function doesn't return anything, in any case, using something like `.every(..)` is more appropriate then using `.reduce(..)` in this case, here is an example:

```js
const rxDetails = [{
    indexID: 1,
    rxInfos: [{
        firstFillIndicator: "Y",
        acceptDigitalFirstFill: "Y",
        rxNumber: "1512"
      },
      {
        firstFillIndicator: "Y",
        acceptDigitalFirstFill: "N",
        rxNumber: "16021"

      }
    ]
  },
  {
    indexID: 2,
    rxInfos: [{
        firstFillIndicator: "Y",
        acceptDigitalFirstFill: "Y",
        rxNumber: "1512"
      },
      {
        firstFillIndicator: "N",
        acceptDigitalFirstFill: "Y",
        rxNumber: "16021"

      }
    ]
  },
  {
    indexID: 3,
    rxInfos: [{
        firstFillIndicator: "Y",
        acceptDigitalFirstFill: "Y",
        rxNumber: "1512"
      },
      {
        firstFillIndicator: "N",
        acceptDigitalFirstFill: "N",
        rxNumber: "16021"

      }
    ]
  }
];


const result = rxDetails.filter(o => {
  return o.rxInfos.every(v => {
    return (v.firstFillIndicator === 'Y' && v.acceptDigitalFirstFill === 'Y') || (v.firstFillIndicator === 'N' && v.acceptDigitalFirstFill === 'N');
  });
});

console.log(result);
```

Comment: thanks for the example thats what i was looking addition to that , is it possible to capture the indexID of the removed object ?

Comment: @hussain You can get all the removed objects using something like this: `const removed = rxDetails.filter(o => !result.some(v => v. indexID === o.indexID))` and then, you can map this array to only keep the IDs `const ids = removed.map(o => o.indexID)`.